# Typescript and Context API, Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context, use-reducer

I am trying to implement Typescript and Context API together in an application. In that case I am trying to make the Context API for the login.

This is the error what I get:
`Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.`

I am not sure what I did wrong, here is my code:

StateProvider.tsx:

```
import React, {
  Reducer,
  Dispatch,
  createContext,
  useContext,
  useReducer,
} from "react";

import  { initialState, LoginState } from "./reducer";

export type StateContextType={
  state: unknown;
  dispatch({}):void;
}

export const StateContext = createContext<StateContextType>({state: {}, dispatch: ()=>{}});

interface IProvider{
  reducer:any;
  initState:typeof initialState;
  children:any;
}

export const StateProvider:React.FC<IProvider> = ({
  reducer,
  initState,
  children,
}) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initState);
  const value = { state, dispatch };
  return (
    <StateContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</StateContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

reducer.tsx:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "./axios";
import { Button, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { useStateValue } from './StateProvider'

export const initialState: LoginState = {
  user: null,
};

export interface LoginState {
  user: string | object | null;
}

type LoginAction = { type: "SET_USER"; payload: string };

function reducer(state: LoginState, action: LoginAction) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_USER":
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default function LoginUseReducer() {
  const {state, dispatch} = useStateValue();

  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const history = useHistory();

  const loginHandler = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = {
      Email: email,
      Password: password,
    };
    axios
      .put("/auth", data)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        dispatch({ type: "SET_USER", payload: response });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
      });
  };

  const handleEmailChange: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (
    event
  ) => {
    setEmail(event.target.value);
  };

  const handlePasswordChange: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (
    event
  ) => {
    setPassword(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <TextField
        label="Email"
        variant="standard"
        helperText="Use your student email (JhonDoe@stud.uni-obuda.hu)"
        value={email}
        onChange={handleEmailChange}
        style={{ width: "80%", marginBottom: 30 }}
      ></TextField>
      <TextField
        label="Password"
        variant="standard"
        type="password"
        value={password}
        onChange={handlePasswordChange}
        style={{ width: "80%" }}
      ></TextField>
      <div className="form_buttons" style={{ marginTop: 30 }}>
        <Button
          onClick={loginHandler}
          style={{ fontSize: "large", padding: 15, width: 100 }}
        >
          Send
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Login.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Login.scss';
import LoginUseReducer, { initialState } from "../../reducer";

function Login() {
    return (
        <div>
            {LoginUseReducer()}
        </div>
    )
}
export default Login;
```

If you guys have any idea, please let me know. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-wildflower-3krss?file=/src/index.tsx) which works as expected, when `LoginUseReducer` is used as a component instead of function as the other user has pointed out. I also made few minor modifications to help catch issues like this.

Comment: Thank you! Your solutions helped me a lot:D

Answer (score 0):

`LoginUseReducer` needs to be rendered like a component and not called like a function

```
function Login() {
    return (
        <div>
            <LoginUseReducer />
        </div>
    )
}
export default Login;
```

Comment: I got the same error:(
The compailer now say the porblem inside the LoginUsereducer's const [email, setEmail] = useState(""); in StateProvider's  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initState); and in the reducer's dispatch({ type: "SET_USER", payload: response });

Comment: Can you show where and how StateProvider component is used

Comment: Sure
index.tsx:
```
import { StateProvider } from './StateProvider';
import reducer, {initialState} from './reducer';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <StateProvider initState={initialState} reducer={reducer} >
    <App />
    </StateProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

```
Then in the reducer what you can see upper, and thats all. I hope it can help you.